# Does email raise an exception when to address is empty

Tags: email, router, dynamics-crm-2016

I have setup a `job` in Dynamics CRM 2016 that runs and create email records.

My question is: An email record is created even if `TO` field is empty, but when CRM tries to send the email, will it raise an exception (to use in try-catch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will crash. It's a good idea to create every email inside a try-catch and skip those who crash.